# Do you know a shortes path algorithm for weighted graphs with hard time windows on the edges and waiting allowed?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Title says it all. I have a weighted Graph G={V,E,ETW} where V is the node set, E the edge set and ETW is a set of edge time windows. A edge time window is a 3-Tuple (edge, starttime, endtime) with the meaning that in the intervall [starttime, endtime] the given edge is not available. The problem now is to find a shortest path from a start node to an end node in which it is allowed to wait at the nodes (to use a edge after it´s time window).

Does anybody know a algorithm for this problem? (and in the best case the paper in which the algorithm was published)

Greetings,
Christoph

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can model your problem via a *time-dependent graph*, which is
a graph with the traversal cost for each edge a function of time.  You could
model your time window by setting the cost to $\infty$ inside your window, making it effectively unavailable, and
constant outside.
Shortest paths in time-dependent graphs have been studied 
since 1966 (Cooke and Halsey), and there is a vast literature.
Here are a two recent references to get you started:

> (1) Demiryurek, Banaei-Kashani, Shahabi,
>   "A Case for Time-Dependent Shortest Path Computation in
>   Spatial Networks."
>   2010 
>   ([ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1869865); [PDF link](http://infolab.usc.edu/DocsDemos/acmgis10_tdsp.pdf))
>
> (2) Ding, Yu, Qin,
>   "Finding time-dependent shortest paths over large graphs."
>   2008 ([ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1353371)).

Comment: Something like this was my first ideal also. But these approaches (at least the ones i know) don´t allow waiting at the nodes. Am i wrong here?

Comment: @Christoph: My understanding is that implicitly they do encompass waiting.